# How to use leaflet-ruler in vue3- typescript

Tags: typescript, leaflet, vuejs3, vite

I am building leaflet map on my Typescript based Vite app (vue3).
I drew the poly line and shapes using 'leaflet-draw', '@types/leaflet-draw'.
Want to add measurement on my map. but can't find '@typs/leaflet-ruler' package and it doesn't exist. I can't figure out the way to use leaflet-ruler in typescript app.
Please let me know the way if you are available.

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the `leaflet-ruler` page that they do not provide TypeScript support (not even through a separate @types package);

[image: leaflet-draw no Typescript support]

On npm, you can check if a package has TypeScript support as follows;

[image: Leaflet @types typescript support]

The [DT] symbol means that it has TypeScript support through a @types package.

[image: vue full Typescript support]

The [TS] symbol means that it has built-in TypeScript support.

Comment: Is there anything that can be done to still use the package even of there are no types available?